# how to reference the parent form from the WPF control

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am using elementhost to host the WPF user control within a windows form. I want to know how to reference the parent form within WPF control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create this relationship programmatically? i.e. when you add your WPF user control into an element host, set the Tag property of the user control to the element host instance.

Colin E.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! After reading all these suggestions on how to utilize commands or events to handle something that should be so simple, I ended up just putting a null variable of my parent form in the usercontrol and setting it to null.  Each time I create an instance of the usercontrol I set the variable to the creating window. Simple!

Answer (score 17):

Here's a way to do it, from within a WPF `UserControl` that has a button in it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(button1);
        var host = (Forms.Integration.ElementHost)Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(source.Handle);
        var form = (Forms.Form)host.TopLevelControl;
        // Show form title
        MessageBox.Show(form.Text);
    }
```

(in this code `Forms` is an alias for `System.Windows.Forms`)

Comment: Works a treat thank you. I would check for nulls though.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you

- expose an event from `WPF child control`,
- register to that event from parent when it is created,
- raise that event whenever you want data from child control,
- make parent control return data by setting values in custom `EventArgs` object.

Accessing a parent control should be avoided unless in some special scenarios. Always propagate events to parent container from children when want to setup communication from child to parent.

Comment: Could you give more detailed reason why not "accessing a parent control should be avoided unless in some special scenarios"

Comment: This sounds very promising, could you give me a link or simply example of what you mean by exposing an event (I think you mean a custom event handler?) and registering it with the parent? So I'm guessing this means that you register the event during the InitializeComponent phase?