# how to change the layout of a control inside a parent wpf form from a child winform?

Tags: wpf, winforms, parent-child

i have two separate projects inside a solution, one is a wpf the other is windows form and i have referenced the winform to the wpf project.. Inside the wpf window is an image control, when clicked, a windows form with a button would appear.

How i can be able to change the image source of the image control inside the wpf form when the button inside the winform is clicked...

i have seen a [similar question to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488719/how-to-reference-the-parent-form-from-the-wpf-control)  but i cant understand the answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a delegate/Action into the Winform to perform the action

Here is a very quick example

**WPF**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // pass in the method you want to call when the winform button is clicked
       var winform = new Form1(() => ChangeImage()).ShowDialog();
    }

    private void ChangeImage()
    {
        // your change image logic
    }
}
```

**Winforms**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Action _action;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_action != null)
        {
            // call the method in the WPF form
            _action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```