# How to get an instance of hosting WinForm from a WPF user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, formclosing

I have a WPF `UserControl` which is being hosted either in a WPF window or in a Windows Forms `Form`. When the user presses the "X" button to close the hosting window/form, I want to grab this closing event and do some operations.

For this purpose I have subscribed to the loading event of the `UserControl` to grab the hosting windows/form instance and subscribe to its closing event.

It is working fine with an WPF window, but when I try to do the same with a `Form`, I get an error and I am unable to proceed.

**WPFUsercontrol.xaml.cs**

```
private void WpfUsercontrol_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (window != null)
        window.Closing += window_closing;

    Form form = this.Parent as Form;    
    //Error: Cannot convert from System.Windows.DependencyObject to System.Windows.Forms.Form    
}
```

How can I achieve the same functionality of closing a `Form` as I am doing with a WPF Window?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488925/2846483) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just cast the WPF `UserControl`'s parent to a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` even when that control is hosted in a Windows Forms `Form`, because hosting is not that trivial and requires additional "black magic".

Instead, you have to get a `HwndSource` first and get its `ElementHost` instance. Having that, you can access the `TopLevelControl` which will be a `Form` you're looking for.

```
var hwndSource = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(this);
var host = (ElementHost)Control.FromChildHandle(hwndSource.Handle);
Form form = (Form)host.TopLevelControl;
```